# Find characters with exactly two occurrences?

Tags: bash, unix

For example, say the string "test this" was inserted to my application -- I only want the s

I'm thinking along the lines of grep wildcards, but I've never really used them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a script.

1. Iterate over each character.
2. Increment a counter for each character per character seen.
3. At the end, check your counters for the one which is equal to `2`.

Comment: actually the question is the script should print all the characters it appears twice, in your 3 rd point., the script is comming out and printing only a single character, and one more thing is if the same character is present one more time I.e. 3 times then again it gives wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure bash implementation of alex' suggestion doing what steve did in `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# your string
string="test this"


# First, make a character array out of it
for ((i=0; i<"${#string}"; i++)); do  # (quotes just for SO higlighting)
    chars[$i]="${string:$i:1}"        # (could be space, so quoted)
done

# associative array will keep track of the count for each character
declare -A counts

# loop through each character and keep track of its count
for ((i=0; i<"${#chars[@]}"; i++)); do # (quotes just for SO higlighting)

    key="${chars[$i]}"              # current character 
                                    # (could be space, so quoted)

    if [ -z counts["$key"] ]; then  # if it doesn't exist yet in counts, 
        counts["$key"]=0;           # initialize it to 0
    else
        ((counts["$key"]++))        # if it exists, increment it
    fi

done

# loop through each key/value and print all with count 2
for key in "${!counts[@]}"; do
    if [ ${counts["$key"]} -eq 2 ]; then
        echo "$key"
    fi
done
```

Note that it uses an associative array, which was introduced in Bash 4.0, so this'll only work on that or newer.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
echo "$string" | awk -F '' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) array[$i]++; for (j in array) if (array[j]==2) print j }'
```